# Properly declaring a variable

Tags: javascript, html

I don't know how to declare a variable here in javascript. I have an example situation that if the paragraph is equals to a, the alert will popup.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<p id="sample">a</p>
</body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var sample = getElementById('sample');

    if (sample == "a") {
        alert("Correct")
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Uhmm... What's the question here?

Comment: How to declare a variable, and how to deliver it?

Comment: In your code `sample` is an html element, not the text from inside it.

Comment: This is not a place to learn programming. This is a place to discuss and solve programming problems. [I recommend this if you are finding an online tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/js/default.asp).

Comment: There are multiple syntax error in the code. Do some javascript beginners course that will be helpful.

Comment: @YongQuan Don’t recommend W3Schools. Their content is often inaccurate, outdated and incomplete. Use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web) instead.

Comment: @Xufox that was many many years ago. Their content now is good enough for beginner and their environment is very beginner friendly. MDN is too complicated for a complete beginner.

Comment: @YongQuan That's incorrect. It's still as bad as ever - maybe worse. Use MDN instead.

Comment: @ScottMarcus try it yourself before commenting

Comment: @YongQuan Yeah, … sorry, I don’t see it. W3Schools still lags miles behind MDN. They _apparently_ became better over the last few years, but it’s still absolutely not “good enough” now and potentially misleading, especially for beginners.

Comment: @YongQuan ??? I've been looking at it since it came online. Can I comment now?

Comment: @ScottMarcus Even w3fools from where you got this image of w3schools has changed its stance. You all should also change now and re read http://www.w3fools.com/. It does not hate w3schools anymore and it is fine to recommend that

Comment: @YongQuan I got my stance from looking at W3Schools. Please don't make assumptions about what others know and where they got that knowledge. Recommend what you want. It's up to you to ignore good advice.

Comment: @Xufox try explaining thermodynamics to a 5 year-old child. They wouldn’t understand a thing until they are at least in high school, unless you explain it to them using a completely misleading way in a college student perspective.

Comment: @ScottMarcus as mentioned by bugswheels94, please reread w3fools, if that even concerns you.

Comment: @YongQuan It doesn't. I don't need a site to tell me that another site is good or bad. I can just look at a site and tell for myself.

Comment: @ScottMarcus ok

Comment: @ScottMarcus May you pleasle provide any example where w3schools is still misinforming? I learned from w3schools 6 years ago when it was bad and now it looks fine to me. It may be very brief which is good for beginners as not everybody can handle a lot of info at start

Comment: @bugwheels94 I don't document errors at W3 Schools, nor am I going to waste my time searching for some. But, I will tell you that I have been a professional IT trainer for over 25 years and consistently (to this day), students will pull up W3 Schools and ask me questions about what they are seeing. And, very often when that happens, I see that the site is incorrect. Usually it relates to the browser compatibility tables or to the descriptions not being accurate. The code may work, but if you leave the site with an incorrect understanding of what the code does or where it can be used, it's bad.

Comment: @ScottMarcus As short as I can be: the above statement is not correct anymore given the lack of evidence and just conclusion based upon years. Check this out: http://dilbert.com/strip/2010-12-23

Comment: @bugwheels94 I really don't see why you seem to feel that you can tell me what my experience is and has been. I told you that the errors persist ***to this day***. If you like it, go for it, but that doesn't change ***actual*** facts.

Answer (score 2):

You're declaring your variable just fine, however if you want the text within the element, you also need to use the `innerHTML` property. And when you use the `getElementById` method, you need to use it on the document object like `document.getElementById`:

```js
var sample = document.getElementById('sample');

if (sample.innerHTML == "a") {
  alert("Correct")
};
```

```html
<p id="sample">a</p>
```

Comment: Don't use `.innerHTML` when the content isn't HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration is fine, but the assignment part is missing `document` as the object which has the **[`.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)** method. Then, once you have the reference to the element, you then need to access its content with **[`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent)** (you can't compare the entire element to a value that the element might contain). As a side note on this, when the string you wish to set/get doesn't contain any HTML, you should use `.textContent` so that the browser doesn't parse the string for HTML unnecessarily. Often, people will suggest that the content of an element should be gotten/set using **[`.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)** and, while that will work, it's wasteful if the string doesn't contain any HTML.

Also, the **[`<script>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script)** must be located within the `head` or the `body`, not outside of them. I would suggest placing it just prior to the closing `body` tag so that by the time the processing reaches the `script`, all of the HTML elements have been parsed into memory and are available.

Lastly (and this is really just a side point), an HTML page also needs the `title` element to have something in it, otherwise it won't be valid. While browsers don't actually do HTML validation, it's important to strive for valid HTML so that you can be sure that your pages will work consistently across all devices. You can validate your HTML at: http://validator.w3.org.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Something Here</title>
</head>
<body>
<p id="sample">a</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var sample = document.getElementById('sample');

    if (sample.textContent == "a") {
        alert("Correct")
    };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @SpencerSanchez You're welcome. Please up vote all helpful answers and consider marking this one as "the" answer (it is more correct than all the others).

Comment: I fail to see how your answer "is more correct than all the others" simply because you chose to use textContent

Comment: @j08691 `.innerHTML` is incorrect here and my answer addresses the incorrect location of the `script` element, which no other answer does.

Comment: Correct position is under head element, is not it? And then defer or async. This is weird that we are discussing over this

Comment: @bugwheels94 `script` may go in the `head` or `body`. If it goes in the head, you may opt to use `defer` or `async` or neither and set up a `DOMContentLoaded` event handler. Or, you can avoid all of that and just place it just before the closing `body` tag, which eliminates the need for that additional code and/or setting up an event handler. It's quite common to take this approach.

Answer (score 0):

`sample` is a variable and you are correct but it is storing a reference to a DOM Element with id sample. To get the inner html of that you need

```
var sample = getElementById('sample').innerHTML;
```

Also, use `===` over `==` for no casting etc. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)

I will recommend you to have a quick look at JS from [w3schools](http://w3schools.com) and then move to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide). Nobody will report you here if you show your efforts, so relax :).